# mysql (5.7) Binlog encryption

Tags: mysql, apache-nifi, mysql-5.7, mysqlbinlog

I am trying to use Binlog feature of mysql to capture changes and feed them to DWH. (my requirement is not for replication).

By looking at official documentation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-binlog-encryption.html) - "From MySQL 8.0.14, binary log files and relay log files can be encrypted.."
Does it mean it's not there for versions 5.x ?

I am trying to enable Binlog for mysql 5.x instances, and wanted to make sure of security.
can I assume it is impossible to have encrypted bin logs for mysql 5.x ?
As i went through the 5.7 documentation , it (encryption) is no where mentioned (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-log.html)

I may try to keep the Binary logs for 2 days probably as I am using Nifi to fetch these logs using CaptureChangeMySQL processor and load them to Data warehouse (DWH).. once the DWH is populated, i dont need the logs anymore.

Please help me with your suggestions or understanding..

Answer (score 0):

The version of mysql 5.7 is also possible, and SSL is recommended. Of course, the encryption of statements like DML/DDL is also related to the binlog_fromat parameter.

Comment: Helloo, Thanks much for responding.. Can you please share any link for documentation that I can do encryption of Binlog in mysql 5.7.. much appreciated..

Comment: @santhosh SSL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-replication-connection-configuration-table.html

Comment: Okay, I am not able to find any encryption related information about binlog files..
But as i search on some documentation, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-data-encryption.html
It is clearly mentioned - "Encryption only applies to data in the tablespace. Data is not encrypted in the redo log, undo log, or binary log." at the end, under "Encryption Limitations".
So I am assuming the Binlog encryption is only possible in 8.X versions but not in 5.X versions.